# How to handle end-of-file error when using read-from-string?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to make use of function [read-from-string](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rd_fro.htm#read-from-string), however i cannot make heads from tails with it.

If i understand documentation correctly, if second parameter is not true, then unbalanced expression in supplied string should not cause an error. However, if in try it out, i get:

> > (read-from-string "(1 2" t 'EOF)
>
> Condition of type: END-OF-FILE Unexpected end of file on
> #<string-input stream from "(1 2">.
>
> Available restarts:
>
> 1. (RESTART-TOPLEVEL) Go back to Top-Level REPL.
>
> Broken at SI:BYTECODES. [Evaluation of: (READ-FROM-STRING "(1 2" ...)]
> In: #<process TOP-LEVEL>.
>
> >> 1
>
> 1
>
> >> (read-from-string "(1 2" nil 'EOF)
>
> Debugger received error of type: END-OF-FILE Unexpected end of file on
> #<string-input stream from "(1 2">. Error flushed.

No matter shat i send, i always get an error.

I am using ECL 15.3.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `eof-error-p` and `eof-value` optional arguments control the result if you hit the end of the string before finding anything at all.  So:

```lisp
> (read-from-string "")

Error: ...
```

while

```lisp
> (read-from-string "" nil 'foo)
foo
0
```

If the end of the string occurs part-way through an incomplete object an error is always signaled.  The spec is clear on this although it's fairly far down the entry:

> If the end of the supplied substring occurs before an object can be read, an error is signaled if eof-error-p is true. An error is signaled if the end of the substring occurs in the middle of an incomplete object.